# Подтверждение почты в проекте Django по коду c django-allauth

Tags: django, email, verification, django-allauth

Подскажите, делаю проект на Django, для работы с регистрацией/авторизацией использую django-allauth, эта библиотека предоставляет подтверждение почты по ссылке в письме, если указать переменную в settings.py ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory". Можно ли и как реализовать с этой библиотекой подтверждение по коду на почте? То есть человек регистрируется(вводит почту, username и пароль) -> далее его перекидывает на страницу, где нужно ввести код, который пришел на почту для её подтверждения -> пользователь вводит код и почта подтверждена.

Или для этого отказываться от использования allauth и делать свою реализацию регистрация/авторизация? Но тогда придется отказаться от входу через другие сервисы(yandex, github, gmail и т.д.)